# How to set text input above the keyboard when clicked? React-Native

Tags: react-native

Currently I have a `TextInput` at the bottom of my screen, when I press the `TextInput` the keyboard is placed on top of the `TextInput`, so I can't see what I am typing. 
Does anyone know how I would be able to show the `TextInput` component just above the keyboard, when the component is pressed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an exact component for this, provided by React Native, [`KeyboardAvoidingView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html).

Comment: I have used the exact thing in the example here (https://aboutreact.com/example-of-request-focus-and-keyboard-avoiding-view-in-react-native/) but still facing the same issue :(
Here is the snack for that https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/example-to-use-keyboard-avoiding-view-and-request-focus-
Can you please help?

Comment: Any reason why this component simply does not do what it is supposed to? It behaves exactly just like a normal `View`, doesn't move the keyboard at all...

Comment: @instanceof You need to set the `behavior` prop.